# Can't access PySide2 from Python 2.7

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyside2

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and have two versions of Python installed: 2.7 and 3.8. When I install PySide2 it's only accessible for Python 3.
Any suggestions how to make it work in all installed Python versions?

Thanks,
Lukas

Comment: No hope. PySide2 (as PyQt5 has) has dropped support for Python 2.x

Comment: And that's good because support for Python 2 was dropped too.

Comment: Thanks for the information!